# <a href=...> in a onclick div

Tags: html, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent

When I'm clicking on a `<div>` hyperlink will not work.

How to modify the code to let the hyperlink work?

The code:

```
<div id="theDiv" onclick="this.style.display='none';">
  ...
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Go to stackoverflow</a>
  <a href="http://...">Go to ...</a>
  <a href="http://...">Go to ...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you don't use onclick attribute?   <div id="theDiv" onclick="alert('HI');">

Comment: A lightbox with many hyperlinks inside the div lightbox, and the outter div's onclick is used to close the lightbox, for example.

Comment: What do you mean the hyperlinks won't work? They seems to follow the link as they should.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
<div id="theDiv" onmousedown="alert('HI');">  
  Go to stackoverflow
</div></a>
```

Comment: The hyperlinks are supposed to be put in the div (for example: lightbox)

Comment: if you put hyperlink inside div then you need to give same height/width of both div and hyperlink.@SFGuru

Answer (score 0):

you set onclick display hidden on div. which set diplay of your div none on click. thats why when you click on div the div become disappear or hide and your hyperlink not working. so remove your onclick style.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the click event from bubbling upto the `<div>` by adding an event handler and invoking `stopPropagation()` method of event object:

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#theDiv a');
[].forEach.call(anchors, function(a) {
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="theDiv" onclick="this.style.display='none';">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Go to stackoverflow</a>
  <a href="http://..." target="_blank">Go to ...</a>
  <a href="http://..." target="_blank">Go to ...</a>
</div>
```